# 'ComplexWarning' when summing up complex values in loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, complex-numbers

I get an 'ComplexWarning' for the code:

```
import numpy as np

A = [np.array([[0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j]]), np.array([[ 0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j]]), np.array([[ 0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j]]), np.array([[ 0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j]]), np.array([[ 0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.j],
   [0.+0.00235702j],
   [0.+0.j]]), np.array([[0],
   [0],       
   [0],
   [0],
   [0],
   [1]])]

for k in range(0, 6):
    C[k] = A[0][k] + A[1][k] + A[2][k] + A[3][k] + A[4][k] + A[5][k]

ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
```

So it does sum up somehow, but discarding the imaginary part and my result is:

```
C = [[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[1]]
```

My problem is, that when I do it manually, e.g. adding up each row by hand by

```
C[0] = A[0][0] + A[1][0] + A[2][0] + A[3][0] + A[4][0] + A[5][0]
```

a.s.o., it just works fine without any errors and my result is

```
C = [[0.+0.j],[0.+0.j],[0.+0.j],[0.+0.j],[0.+0.00235702j],[1.+0.j]]
```

I don't see, why the use of a loop to sum up the rows of my matrices gives an error, while it works otherwise. And I can't do it by hand, since it is just a small part in a bigger calculation, which in the end shut end up doing this summing for approximately 6000 times.
Anyone seen this error before and knows what to do?

Comment: How do you create `C` in the not working case?

Comment: Via the for loop I've presented in the first piece of code I posted. Just scroll down.

Comment: You misunderstand, I'm interested in a line along the lines of `C = np.zeros(something)` or some such. In other words: I'm very very sure that dtype of C is float and as such assigning an array to C (what you're doing) will automatically cast the complex values to floats.

Comment: Ah, all right. I create `C` as an array: `C = np.array([[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]])`. Are the entries float in this way? How do I change that?

Comment: Yeppers, that's it there. The dtype of that will be integer. You can either pass an explicit dtype like `np.array(..., dtype=np.complex128)`, or make one (or more) of the values complex: `np.array([[0j], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]])`. I'd personally go with passing the *dtype* argument.

Comment: Or you could just `np.zeros((6,1), dtype=np.complex128)`.

Comment: Thank you. I solved it now by defining `C` as `C =np.array([[0. + 0.j], [0. + 0.j], [0. + 0.j], [0. + 0.j], [0. + 0.j], [0. + 0.j]])`, but your way seems more elegant.